# i want to run a cron job once and have to stop it this syntax "* * * * *" is working fine but this syntax is not working 05 17 18 2 5

Tags: cron, node-cron

I need to run cron once at a particular tine and after that have to stop the job

```
const cron = require("node-cron");
const SendEmail = (payload) => {
  console.log("SENDING EMAIL", payload);
};
const ScheduleCronJob = (payload, cronTime) => {
  console.log("ScheduleCronJob.........", cronTime);
  const job = cron.schedule(cronTime, () => {
  console.log("You will see this message every second");
  SendEmail(payload);
  job.stop();
});
  return job;
};
const payload = { name: "sarath" };
const job = ScheduleCronJob(payload, "05 17 18 2 5");
job.start();
```

I am starting and stopping the `cron` job this is not working fine for me. if i replace with "* * * * *" then it is working fine.
can anyone explain wher i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `cron` schedule `05 17 18 2 5` is set to:

```
 At 17:05 on day-of-month 18 and on Friday in February.
```

Suggesting to [test your `cron` schedule in here](https://crontab.guru/).

Suggesting to pay attention to timezone calculation in `node-cron`

Stopping the current job is not related to future process that started by `contab` at some time in the future.

You need to use `pkill` command or `killall` command with full path to the process command or the pid.
Suggesting to study `node-cron` documentation about pid and process names.

Comment: its working when i change the timestamp region     {
      scheduled: false,
      timezone: "Asia/Kolkata",
    }, its running but its not stoping the job

Comment: see my additional comments